# Updating Gridview from formview in Update panel (Part 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

Firstly, my program works well, it does what I want it to do, I just want to avoid having to refresh.

So I tried several different solutions that were suggested to me but my update panel seems to still not be working.  I have 2 gridviews and 2 formviews.  I tried adding triggers, Calling updatepanel1.update() on methods, adding autopostback='true' on every textbox, etc. I have them all in my program just to try and narrow down to what actually will let me see the a gridview's new record from the insert on the formview without refreshing the page.  If someone can still give me an idea of what I'm missing, that would be great.  I'm just going to copy my whole 2 files.

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PO_1_5_15
{
    public partial class _Webform : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
            {
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)FormView1.FindControl("UpdateButton");
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lb);
            }

            if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
            {
                LinkButton lb2 = (LinkButton)FormView1.FindControl("InsertButton");
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lb2);
            }

            if (FormView2.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
            {
                LinkButton lb3 = (LinkButton)FormView1.FindControl("UpdateButton");
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lb3);
            }

            if (FormView2.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
            {
                LinkButton lb4 = (LinkButton)FormView1.FindControl("InsertButton");
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lb4);
            }

            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void FormsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel1.Update();

        }
        protected void FormsView1_ItemDeleted(object sender, DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
        protected void FormsView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
            FormView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
        protected void GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FormView1.DataBind();
            FormView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();

        }



        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {


            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }



        protected void FormView2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }












    }
}
```

HTML Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Webform.aspx.cs" Inherits="PO_1_5_15._Webform" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ContentTemplate >




        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PO_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PO_ID" HeaderText="PO_ID" SortExpression="PO_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PO_Title" HeaderText="PO_Title" SortExpression="PO_Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Received" HeaderText="Date_Received" SortExpression="Date_Received" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Completed" HeaderText="Date_Completed" SortExpression="Date_Completed" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PO_Note" HeaderText="PO_Note" SortExpression="PO_Note" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserDate" HeaderText="UserDate" SortExpression="UserDate" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PO_ID], [PO_Title], [Date_Received], [Date_Completed], [Username], [PO_Note], [UserDate] FROM [PO_Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PO_AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" EnableModelValidation="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                PO_AutoID:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_AutoIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PO_AutoID") %>' />
                <br />
                PO_ID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' AutoPostBack="True" />
                <br />
                PO_Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Date_Received:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Date_ReceivedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Date_Completed:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Date_CompletedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />

                PO_Note:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                PO_ID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                PO_Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Date_Received:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Date_ReceivedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Date_Completed:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Date_CompletedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />

                PO_Note:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                PO_AutoID:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_AutoIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PO_AutoID") %>' />
                <br />
                PO_ID:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
                <br />
                PO_Title:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' />
                <br />
                Date_Received:
                <asp:Label ID="Date_ReceivedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' />
                <br />
                Date_Completed:
                <asp:Label ID="Date_CompletedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' />
                <br />
                Username:
                <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                <br />
                UserDate:
                <asp:Label ID="UserDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserDate") %>' />
                <br />
                PO_Note:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_NoteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DeletePO" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="InsertPO" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PO_Table] WHERE ([PO_ID] = @PO_ID)" UpdateCommand="UpdatePO" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Received" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Completed" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Note" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserDate" Type="DateTime" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="PO_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Received" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Completed" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Note" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Task_AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" EnableModelValidation="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Task_AutoID" HeaderText="Task_AutoID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Task_AutoID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PO_AutoID" HeaderText="PO_AutoID" SortExpression="PO_AutoID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PO_ID" HeaderText="PO_ID" SortExpression="PO_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Task_Title" HeaderText="Task_Title" SortExpression="Task_Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserDate" HeaderText="UserDate" SortExpression="UserDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="Cost" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="_Status" HeaderText="_Status" SortExpression="_Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Invoice_Date" HeaderText="Invoice_Date" SortExpression="Invoice_Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Paid_Date" HeaderText="Paid_Date" SortExpression="Paid_Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Task_Note" HeaderText="Task_Note" SortExpression="Task_Note" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Task]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Task_AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" EnableModelValidation="True" OnPageIndexChanging="FormView2_PageIndexChanging" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                Task_AutoID:
                <asp:Label ID="Task_AutoIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Task_AutoID") %>' />
                <br />

                PO_ID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Task_Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Task_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task_Title") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />

                Cost:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CostTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cost") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                _Status:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("_Status") %>' AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                Invoice_Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Invoice_DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_Date") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Paid_Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Paid_DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Paid_Date") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Task_Note:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Task_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task_Note") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <InsertItemTemplate>


                PO_ID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Task_Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Task_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task_Title") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />

                Cost:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CostTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cost") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                _Status:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("_Status") %>' AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                Invoice_Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Invoice_DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_Date") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Paid_Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Paid_DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Paid_Date") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                Task_Note:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Task_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task_Note") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Task_AutoID:
                <asp:Label ID="Task_AutoIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Task_AutoID") %>' />
                <br />
                PO_AutoID:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_AutoIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_AutoID") %>' />
                <br />
                PO_ID:
                <asp:Label ID="PO_IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
                <br />
                Task_Title:
                <asp:Label ID="Task_TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task_Title") %>' />
                <br />
                Username:
                <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                <br />
                UserDate:
                <asp:Label ID="UserDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserDate") %>' />
                <br />
                Cost:
                <asp:Label ID="CostLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cost") %>' />
                <br />
                _Status:
                <asp:Label ID="_StatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("_Status") %>' />
                <br />
                Invoice_Date:
                <asp:Label ID="Invoice_DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_Date") %>' />
                <br />
                Paid_Date:
                <asp:Label ID="Paid_DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Paid_Date") %>' />
                <br />
                Task_Note:
                <asp:Label ID="Task_NoteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task_Note") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Task] WHERE [Task_AutoID] = @Task_AutoID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Task] ([PO_AutoID], [PO_ID], [Task_Title], [Username], [UserDate], [Cost], [_Status], [Invoice_Date], [Paid_Date], [Task_Note]) VALUES (@PO_AutoID, @PO_ID, @Task_Title, SUSER_SNAME(), SYSDATETIME(), @Cost, @_Status, @Invoice_Date, @Paid_Date, @Task_Note);

" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Task] WHERE ([Task_AutoID] = @Task_AutoID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Task] SET [PO_AutoID] = @PO_AutoID, [PO_ID] = @PO_ID, [Task_Title] = @Task_Title, [Username] = SUSER_SNAME(), [UserDate] =  SYSDATETIME(), [Cost] = @Cost, [_Status] = @_Status, [Invoice_Date] = @Invoice_Date, [Paid_Date] = @Paid_Date, [Task_Note] = @Task_Note WHERE [Task_AutoID] = @Task_AutoID


">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Task_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="_Status" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Paid_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Note" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView2" Name="Task_AutoID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="_Status" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Paid_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Note" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Task_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
       </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="DataBound" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="DataBinding" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="Disposed" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="Init" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemCommand" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemCreated" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemDeleted" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemDeleting" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemInserted" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemInserting" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemUpdated" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ItemUpdating" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="Load" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ModeChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="ModeChanging" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="PreRender" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView1" EventName="Unload" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="DataBinding" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="DataBound" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="Disposed" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="Init" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemCommand" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemCreated" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemDeleted" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemDeleting" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemInserted" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemInserting" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemUpdated" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ItemUpdating" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="Load" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ModeChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="ModeChanging" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FormView2" EventName="PreRender" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="Unload" />
            </Triggers>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way too much code here.  The purpose of a postback is to submit changed form data to the server.  This needs to happen exactly once, not every time a user changes a field.

You have to realize that even with an UpdataPanel a FULL postback occurs every time you post.  The only difference is that the only part of the page is sent back to the update panel.  Basically you cut down on page flicker, not server overhead. And you have a LOT of Autoposting going on.

My advice.  remove the update panels, get the Formviews and Gridviews to work with as few postbacks as possible THEN wrap them in update panels.  Lose all the autopostbacks on the TextBoxen.  The only things that should be firing postbacks are your save buttons.  Even validation should be done clientside where possible.

Comment: Yes, I know I over-did it with the code, but I know there are several techniques used in implementing the update panel.  The only postbacks I have are from the dropdown on the "Status".  So where exactly should I be using the autopostback?  There's not an option for it on the link buttons such as update, insert, and delete.  Can I just wrap all my controls in one update panel?  Do I use "UpdatePanel1.Update();" on any methods or multiple methods or is that not necessary?

Comment: I meant to add in my first sentence that of course it's not efficient to add a bunch of useless code. but I was just narrowing down the possibilities.  Anyway, yeah, do I need for update panels for my 2 gridviews and 2 formviews?  I tried 1 , but that didn't work?

Comment: you don't need any update panels to update the gridviews but since you're not editing via gridview the griviews need to be rebound after a successful insert or update via the formviews.  Using the updatepanel only makes it so only a portion of the page transmitted back to the browser, it has nothing to do with updating the gridview.

Comment: Oh and as for autopostback - generally speaking you use that feature when you need to hit the server to update the page to show the user a result.  The ddls should be autopost as they are intended to show the user a reduced dataset in the gridviews, the problem is every time you post back you are "rewriting" the select statement with the current values from the DDL's  which are reset to item 0 if you are not saving and restoring the DDL selected values properly.